# Multiline expressions in an aligned equation environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

The following block...

```
\begin{aligned}
L(\text{dn} = 1) &= P(\mathbf{A_c}, \mathbf{A_m}, \mathbf{A_f}, \mathbf{R_c}, \mathbf{R_m}, \mathbf{R_f} \mid \text{dn} = 1) \\
                 &= P(\mathbf{A_c}, \mathbf{A_m}, \mathbf{A_f}, \mathbf{R_c}, \mathbf{R_m}, \mathbf{R_f} \mid v_c = 0/1, v_m = 0/0, v_f = 0/0) \\
                 &= P(\mathbf{A_c} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(\mathbf{A_m} \mid v_m = 0/0) P(\mathbf{A_f} \mid v_f = 0/0) \\
                 &\quad \enskip P(\mathbf{R_c} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(\mathbf{R_m} \mid v_m = 1/1) P(\mathbf{R_f} \mid v_f = 1/1) \\
                 &= \prod^{n}_{i=1} P(A_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(A_{m_i} \mid v_m = 0/0) P(A_{f_i} \mid v_f = 0/0) \\
                 &\quad \qquad P(R_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(R_{m_i} \mid v_m = 1/1) P(R_{f_i} \mid v_f = 1/1)
\end{aligned}
```

...produces this typeset result.

[image: Gnarly equation]

The third and fourth right-hand-side expressions are too long to fit on one line, so I have abused a combination of line breaks, `\quad`s, `\qquad`s, and `\enskip`s for alignment. Despite my efforts, the alignment remains a bit off, and in any case I'd prefer a cleaner solution than my dirty hack.

Any suggestions for how to align these expressions correctly?

Comment: Are you sure it's `\mathbf{A_m}` and not `\mathbf{A}_m`?

Comment: @egreg I think you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't align at all costs: continuation lines will be ambiguous if aligned with the previous line.

I suggest to add an operation symbol to remove the ambiguity and also a pair of parentheses in the last line.

I'm not sure about the boldface subscripts: if they correspond on both sides of the vertical bar, they should be typeset the same so either all boldface or all italic. Here I choose all italic. If they should be all boldface (except possibly in the last line), it should be

```
\mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{c}}
```

for uniformity. I suggest to define your own command for such variables, as I do below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\dn}{\mathrm{dn}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
L(\dn = 1)
&= P(\bv{A}_c,\bv{A}_m,\bv{A}_f,\bv{R}_c,\bv{R}_m,\bv{R}_f \mid \dn = 1) \\
&= P(\bv{A}_c,\bv{A}_m,\bv{A}_f,\bv{R}_c,\bv{R}_m,\bv{R}_f \mid
     v_c = 0/1, v_m = 0/0, v_f = 0/0)
\\
&= \begin{aligned}[t]
   & P(\bv{A}_c \mid v_c = 0/1)
     P(\bv{A}_m \mid v_m = 0/0)
     P(\bv{A}_f \mid v_f = 0/0)
     \\
   &\cdot
     P(\bv{R}_c \mid v_c = 0/1)
     P(\bv{R}_m \mid v_m = 1/1)
     P(\bv{R}_f \mid v_f = 1/1)
   \end{aligned}
\\
&= \prod^{n}_{i=1}
   \begin{aligned}[t]
   \bigl(
   & P(A_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1)
     P(A_{m_i} \mid v_m = 0/0)
     P(A_{f_i} \mid v_f = 0/0)
   \\
   &\cdot
     P(R_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1)
     P(R_{m_i} \mid v_m = 1/1)
     P(R_{f_i} \mid v_f = 1/1)
     \bigr)
   \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Agreed. I see how this is much less ambiguous. Would it be confusing to have the parentheses span the two lines?

Comment: @DanielStandage Yes.

Answer (score 4):

I think this produces the alignment that you ask for but to be honest I wouldn't align the continuation lines, I'd add at least `\quad` offset to make it clearer that they are continuations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

why not align for the outer environment?\\
$\begin{aligned}
L(\text{dn} = 1) &= P(\mathbf{A_c}, \mathbf{A_m}, \mathbf{A_f}, \mathbf{R_c}, \mathbf{R_m}, \mathbf{R_f} \mid \text{dn} = 1) \\
                 &= P(\mathbf{A_c}, \mathbf{A_m}, \mathbf{A_f}, \mathbf{R_c}, \mathbf{R_m}, \mathbf{R_f} \mid v_c = 0/1, v_m = 0/0, v_f = 0/0) \\
                 &=
\begin{aligned}[t]& P(\mathbf{A_c} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(\mathbf{A_m} \mid v_m = 0/0) P(\mathbf{A_f} \mid v_f = 0/0) \\
                 &P(\mathbf{R_c} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(\mathbf{R_m} \mid v_m = 1/1) P(\mathbf{R_f} \mid v_f = 1/1)
\end{aligned}\\
                 &= \prod^{n}_{i=1}
\begin{aligned}[t]& P(A_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(A_{m_i} \mid v_m = 0/0) P(A_{f_i} \mid v_f = 0/0) \\
                 &P(R_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(R_{m_i} \mid v_m = 1/1) P(R_{f_i} \mid v_f = 1/1)\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish I could award two "accepted" answers. This answer does the best job of asking the question as posed, but egreg's answer offered a solution with improved readability and less chance for misinterpretation.

Comment: @DanielStandage well yes, as I commented in the answer, the alignment here isn't clearly desired:-) Shame about voting for egreg though:-)

Answer (score 2):

Just move the alignment character (`&`) to the right of the equals and an `{}` to get the spacing right (Thanks to David Carlisle for this one!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
L(\text{dn} = 1) = {}& P(\mathbf{A_c}, \mathbf{A_m}, \mathbf{A_f}, \mathbf{R_c}, \mathbf{R_m}, \mathbf{R_f} \mid \text{dn} = 1) \\
                 = {}& P(\mathbf{A_c}, \mathbf{A_m}, \mathbf{A_f}, \mathbf{R_c}, \mathbf{R_m}, \mathbf{R_f} \mid v_c = 0/1, v_m = 0/0, v_f = 0/0) \\
                 = {}& P(\mathbf{A_c} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(\mathbf{A_m} \mid v_m = 0/0) P(\mathbf{A_f} \mid v_f = 0/0) \\
                   {}& P(\mathbf{R_c} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(\mathbf{R_m} \mid v_m = 1/1) P(\mathbf{R_f} \mid v_f = 1/1) \\
                 = {}& \prod^{n}_{i=1} P(A_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(A_{m_i} \mid v_m = 0/0) P(A_{f_i} \mid v_f = 0/0) \\
                   {}& P(R_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(R_{m_i} \mid v_m = 1/1) P(R_{f_i} \mid v_f = 1/1)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The result will be:

[image]

Comment: You do not get relation spacing around `=` if used that way (you need `={}&` )

Comment: Hmmmm... Indeed. I didn't notice that. If I'm correct, the spacing after an equals sign is a `\thickmuskip`. Would adding this after the `&` be correct?

Comment: just add `{}` after the =

Answer (score 2):

You can nest  `aligned`s in `align*`, like in one of these variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, relsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
L(\text{dn} = 1) &= P(\mathbf{A_c}, \mathbf{A_m}, \mathbf{A_f}, \mathbf{R_c}, \mathbf{R_m}, \mathbf{R_f} \mid \text{dn} = 1) \\
                 &= P(\mathbf{A_c}, \mathbf{A_m}, \mathbf{A_f}, \mathbf{R_c}, \mathbf{R_m}, \mathbf{R_f} \mid v_c = 0/1, v_m = 0/0, v_f = 0/0) \\
                 &= \begin{aligned}[t] & P(\mathbf{A_c} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(\mathbf{A_m} \mid v_m = 0/0) P(\mathbf{A_f} \mid v_f = 0/0) \\[-1ex]
                 & P(\mathbf{R_c} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(\mathbf{R_m} \mid v_m = 1/1) P(\mathbf{R_f} \mid v_f = 1/1)
                 \end{aligned}\\
                 &= \mathlarger{\prod^{n}_{i=1}}\begin{aligned} & P(A_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(A_{m_i} \mid v_m = 0/0) P(A_{f_i} \mid v_f = 0/0) \\[-1ex]
                 & P(R_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(R_{m_i} \mid v_m = 1/1) P(R_{f_i} \mid v_f = 1/1)
                 \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
L(\text{dn} = 1) &= P(\mathbf{A_c}, \mathbf{A_m}, \mathbf{A_f}, \mathbf{R_c}, \mathbf{R_m}, \mathbf{R_f} \mid \text{dn} = 1) \\
                 &= P(\mathbf{A_c}, \mathbf{A_m}, \mathbf{A_f}, \mathbf{R_c}, \mathbf{R_m}, \mathbf{R_f} \mid v_c = 0/1, v_m = 0/0, v_f = 0/0) \\
                 &= \begin{aligned}[t] & P(\mathbf{A_c} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(\mathbf{A_m} \mid v_m = 0/0) P(\mathbf{A_f} \mid v_f = 0/0) \\[-1ex]
                 & P(\mathbf{R_c} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(\mathbf{R_m} \mid v_m = 1/1) P(\mathbf{R_f} \mid v_f = 1/1)
                 \end{aligned}\\
                 &=\begin{multlined}[t] \smash[b]{\prod^{n}_{i=1}} P(A_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(A_{m_i} \mid v_m = 0/0) P(A_{f_i} \mid v_f = 0/0) \\[1.5ex]
                  \times\smash[t]{\prod^{n}_{i=1}}P(R_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1) P(R_{m_i} \mid v_m = 1/1) P(R_{f_i} \mid v_f = 1/1)
                 \end{multlined}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I fully disagree with the typesetting of the last line.

Comment: @egreg: What's wrong with this way? That's the most compact I could imagine. Of course, one might repeat the product symbol  the second line.

Comment: Readers will most likely have doubts about its meaning. Also the upper line is difficult to understand.

Comment: @egreg: I've added another variant. I think it's less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

> Multiline expressions in an aligned equation environment

Analyzing the problem carefully, it is a `split` environment of aligned equations in which two of the equations are multi-line equations, for they being too long and whose second parts should be right justified (or right aligned, or `\shoveright`, or `\MoveEqRight`...).

You need two **nested `multline` environments** `multilined[t]` inside a `\split` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        L((\mathrm{dn} = 1)
        &= P(\mathbf{A}_c,\mathbf{A}_m,\mathbf{A}_f,\mathbf{R}_c,\mathbf{R}_m,\mathbf{R}_f \mid \mathrm{dn} = 1)
        \\
        &= P(\mathbf{A}_c,\mathbf{A}_m,\mathbf{A}_f,\mathbf{R}_c,\mathbf{R}_m,\mathbf{R}_f \mid
        v_c = 0/1, v_m = 0/0, v_f = 0/0)
        \\
        &= \begin{multlined}[t]
            P(\mathbf{A}_c \mid v_c = 0/1)
            P(\mathbf{A}_m \mid v_m = 0/0)
            P(\mathbf{A}_f \mid v_f = 0/0)
            \\
            \cdot
            P(\mathbf{R}_c \mid v_c = 0/1)
            P(\mathbf{R}_m \mid v_m = 1/1)
            P(\mathbf{R}_f \mid v_f = 1/1)
        \end{multlined}
        \\
        &= \prod^{n}_{i=1}
        \begin{multlined}[t]
        \bigl(P(A_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1)
        P(A_{m_i} \mid v_m = 0/0)
        P(A_{f_i} \mid v_f = 0/0)
        \\
        \cdot
        P(R_{c_i} \mid v_c = 0/1)
        P(R_{m_i} \mid v_m = 1/1)
        P(R_{f_i} \mid v_f = 1/1)
        \bigr)
        \end{multlined}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The solution may seem obvious now, but I came across it after two hours of playing around with `align`, `gather`, `multline`, `split`, `alginat`, `flalign` and all its variants; just before I was about to contact Lars Mad­sen (main­tainer of the `mathtools` package) for an upgrade. It had to be something with an automated format, *in pure LaTeX style*, not through the use of `\quad` or `\hspace` or `\vphantom` or the like.

It is amazing how such a basic typesetting feature is so unknown. I mean, I couldn't find a solution in the whole Internet! It ought to be included in the the guides and tutorials. Multi-line equations are in our day to day.

I knew there had to be more people demanding a solution to this, which I'm now sharing throughout the forum. It also proves how robust the coding of the `mathtools` package is, responding successfully to this workaround.

Enjoy!

Comment: I think that is the better solution and I definitly use this for my future multiline equations.